# How can I quickly remove unused formulae from the bottom of the spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The person who built the spreadsheets used a shortcut to copy the formulae down the entire column, although most of them only have a few hundred active rows.  This is making the file size huge and almost unworkable.

How can I quickly remove all this to make the files more manageable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the entire row with the lowest row reference to be deleted <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> and Delete, then Save.